# Tracking clusters across different time periods

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, cluster-analysis

I am relatively new to Python, and I am having the following issue: I am trying to cluster customers across two time periods (two distinct data sets). The k-mean clustering results are stored in a pandas data frame, with columns 'name', 'clustering_period_1' and 'clustering_period_2'. As clustering labels do not carry any meaning across clustering periods, I want to re-assign the labels in 'clustering_period_2'.

Method: I want to figure out for each clustering output of period 1 and period 2, how often a combination has occurred, e.g. how often was an observation assigned to cluster 1 in period 1, and cluster 5 in period 2. I do this using the pivot_table function:

```
    df.pivot_table(index='cluster', columns='cluster_2', values='name', aggfunc='count')
```

I then want to find the maximum value in the 'pivot table':

```
    cluster_period_2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
    cluster_period_1                              
    0                  51  43  50  49  32  36  33
    1                  26  28  17  34  25  28  30
    2                  34  47  35  33  37  36  34
    3                   7   6   2   5   7   5   6
    4                  30  19  24  26  20  18  20
    5                   3  11   5   6   4   6   3
    6                   4   2   1  13   2   4   3
```

In this example, this would be 51, which implies that cluster_0_period_1 is now cluster_0_in_period_2. Then, I want to find the next largest value not in an already used column and row, i.e. not in row 0 or column 0. This is 47, implying that cluster_2_period_1 is now cluster_1_period_2. I want to do this until I end up with a complete list, e.g. (example below not based on pivot table values):

```
    cluster_0_period_1 -> cluster_0_period_2
    cluster_1_period_1 -> cluster_4_period_2
    ...
    cluster_6_period_1 -> cluster_5_period_2
```

How do I best implement this? Or if there is a completely different methods that makes more sense (e.g. dictionaries or list-based), please feel free to suggest.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We doing the `stack`

```
df1=df.stack().to_frame('val').reset_index()
A=[]
B=[]
for x,y in df1.groupby('cluster_period_1'):
    y=y.loc[~y['cluster_period_2'].isin(A),:]
    A.append(y['cluster_period_2'].loc[y.val.idxmax()])
    B.append(y.val.idxmax())
    print(A)
    print(y)
```

Then

```
df1.loc[B]
Out[472]: 
    cluster_period_1 cluster_period_2  val
0                  0                0   51
10                 1                3   34
15                 2                1   47
25                 3                4    7
30                 4                2   24
40                 5                5    6
48                 6                6    3
```

Comment: "_We doing the `stack`_" I like how you say this. xD

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ haha:-)  Need time to improve my communication skills :-)

Answer (score 0):

This greeedy approach may not find the best asssignment.

Instead, use the [Hungarian algorithm (Kuhn-Minutes)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Also, you can increase your chances of stability by using the center from the previous period as starting conditions.

In above example, there is so little similarity between the two clusterings, I would reject the hypothesis that you can map/track the cluster centers. It's not unusual for k-means to be instable, this often just hints that it did not work well anyway.

You may also want to use, e.g., ARI and AMI to measure the similarity of the two cluster assignments. If these give you a low value, it does not make sense to find a 1 on 1 mapping.

Comment: Thanks for this post! In this context, what do AMI and ARI stand for?

Comment: Adjusted Rand Index, Adjusted Mutual Information. Standard measures for cluster evaluation.